# Prove that exist $b \gt 0$, so that $f$ may be defined at $x=0$ and be continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

Given the function $$   
f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       (1 + 2^{\frac{3}{x}})^{bsin(x)} &\quad if \quad x\gt 0 \\
                                  \\
       \frac{arctan(9bx)}{x} &\quad if \quad x\lt 0           \\ 
     \end{cases}
$$

Prove that exist $b \gt 0$, so that $f$ may be defined at $x=0$ and be continuous.

**My procedure**:

(1) $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{arctan(9bx)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{arctan(9bx)-arctan(9b*0)}{x} = \frac d{dx}arctan(9bx)|_{x=0}=\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+(9bx)^2}9b\Bigr)|_{x=0}=9b=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{arctan(9bx)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{arctan(9bx)}{x}$$

Then the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{arctan(9bx)}{x}$ exist.

(2) $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} (1 + 2^{\frac{3}{x}})^{bsin(x)} = \infty^0 \;(indetermination)$$
The thing is I don´t really know how to calculate the second limit. Any hint in how to proceed with the limit?. Preferably **without** using L'Hopitals rule.

Comment: You can take log then apply l'Hopital...

Comment: I would like to find the limit using only properties, substitution and orders of magnitud, not using l'hopital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to compute the right-side limit. Assume henceforth $x>0$.
$$\log(1+2^{3/x})^{b\sin x}=b\sin x\log(1+2^{3/x})=b\sin x\log(2^{3/x}(1+2^{-3/x}))=b\sin x\frac{3}{x}\log 2+o(x)$$
So the logarithm of the expression tends, as $x\downarrow 0$, to $3b\log 2$.

Comment: That result only works when you are taking the right limit of $(1 + 2^{\frac{3}{x}})^{bsin(x)}$, witch is the case, so that would be it. But would happen if I take the left limit?, then$ (1 + 2^{\frac{-3}{x}})$ would not tend to $0$.

Comment: Of course it is the right limit. It is defined for $x>0$. You already have computed the left limit yourself.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But what I was asking is what would be the procedure to compute the left limit of $(1 + 2^{\frac{3}{x}})^{bsin(x)}$, not that is needed here, just out of curiosity.